# Contravariant tensor of rank 2 from the product of two contravariant vectors

Tags: tensors

I am currently reading through "Introducing Einstein's Relativity" by Ray D'inverno and it states, "An example of such a quantity is the provided by the product $Y^aZ^b$, say, of two contravariant vectors $Y^a$ and $Z^b$."

Where "quantity" is referring to a contravariant tensor of rank 2. My understanding is that a contravariant vector is represented as a column vector and that you cannot multiple two column vectors.

So how do you go about calculating the product of two contravariant vectors?

Thank you

Comment: Read up on "Kronecker product", vector multiplication only does not work (in general) when you expect that the result is a vector of the same space.

Comment: Is it normal to call the Kronecker product just the product then? I've also seen a statement identical to what Ray makes on science direct (sourced from "M. Dalarsson, N. Dalarsson, in Tensors, Relativity, and Cosmology (Second Edition), 2015"). I also find it strange that in both examples, neither use the Kronecker product circle with a cross.

Comment: The Kronecker product is used in actual matrix constructions, here it is just one "visual" realization of a tensor product. There are different traditions in math and physics on how to write tensors. Physics is more interested in coordinates and their transformations, math in geometric objects. Math would write this as $Y\otimes Z=Y^aZ^b+e_a\otimes e_b$, which neatly encompasses the coordinate change dance. For physics the mentioning of the basis vectors is too long and redundant.

Comment: Okay thank you!